# How to tell where I am in an array with pointer arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers

In C, I have declared a memory area like this:

```
int cells = 512;
int* memory = (int*) malloc ((sizeof (int)) * cells);
```

And I place myself more or less in the middle

```
int* current_cell = memory + ((cells / 2) * sizeof (int));
```

My question is, while I increment `*current_cell`, how do I know if I reached the end of the allocated memory area?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (current_cell >= memory + cells)
   no_longer_in_valid_memory;
```

However! You have a large problem in your code. If you want current_cell to be somewhere near the middle of the memory region, you should actually do this:

```
int* current_cell = memory + (cells / 2);
```

The pointer arithmetic will take care of the multiplying by sizeof(int).

Answer (score 3):

While you're within  the valid indices the following holds true:

```
memory <= current_cell && current_cell < memory + cells
```

so if you only increment the address it's enough to check for

```
current_cell < memory + cells
```

however be careful - you might increment the address by such a bug value that it overflows and becomes less than `memory`. Only use the second simpilfied condition if you're sure overflow can't happen.

Comment: are you sure it's not cells*sizeof int? that was my doubt.

Comment: @klez: Certainly no `*sizeof()`. With a `type*` pointer `(type + N)` points onto the Nth element - the compiler will do the `*sizeof(Type)` multiplication.

Comment: It is not.  When you use + or - with a pointer and an integral type, it adds or subtracts *elements*, not bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> And I place myself more or less in the middle
>
> ```
> int* current_cell = memory + ((cells / 2) * sizeof (int));
> ```

Actually, no. The *correct* expression would be:

```
int* middle = memory + cells / 2;
```

since pointer arithmetic takes the type of the pointer into account. In other words, this expression:

```
memory + 1
```

increments the pointer not by a single byte but by `sizeof(int)` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The index in the array, which starts at `memory`, equivalent to the pointer `current`, is just `current - memory` -- the "scaling" (by `sizeof(int)`) is taken care of for you.  So, you know the pointer is valid (i.e., within the bounds of the `cells`-long array starting at `memory`) if and only if the index is `>=0` and `<cells` (from 0 to 511 included, in your example):

```
((current - memory) >= 0) && ((current - memory) < cells)
```